# Migrating data from Package Version x to Package Version y with deleted data

Tags: managed-package, data-migration, delete-field-beta

Ok,

A follow up to my question here: [Unable to access Deleted field (from managed package) from Apex but can from Dev Console](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49853/unable-to-access-deleted-field-from-managed-package-from-apex-but-can-from-dev/49863#49863)

So, we have deleted fields and want to use a post install script to move the data from those fields to a new custom object.

1. In the package org, a class has been written to perform the migration
2. The package is not installed in the package org (as it cannot be installed there duh)
3. There is no option to set the package version dependency

So when I install it in the target org, the migration class is versioned to the new version of the package and the fields are not present so it never migrates the data

The class deploys because we use dynamic methods to get the fields and try catch in case the fields do not exist (user deleted)

BUT, there is no way that I can see to version the class for an earlier version of the package so the migration never occurs.

Short of going into every org and running a script in dev console, what would be a way to accomplish this.

Reason for the requirement: Updating code from a package from a previous poorly developed model with 10-30 lookup fields. They are being moved to a related object and the data from those fields needs to be migrated to records in that object.

09-24-2014 - UPDATE: High fives to Tech Evangelists - Issue is now being discuss with R&D to see if there is a way to accommodate this "feature hole" (as I am calling it)

Comment: Sounds like a platform mechanism like the [InstallHandler](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_install_handler.htm) but that runs before the install starts rather than after it is needed...

Comment: I have logged a case, lets see if I can cause enough of a stir to actually be put in contact with the Packaging team....

Comment: ugh.. I cannot get past the "we were unable to locate a similar issue please provide us with org id, yada yada yada...." even though I stated it is not a bug but a feature hole and to put me in contact with the packaging beta team. Can't get past the initial partner support triage.......Oh well. - Am I missing something or is cases the only way to communicate issues related to a beta feature? There should be something closer to the beta team than cases

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating an intermediate version before the field deletion containing both old and new fields accessible. Then run the migration scripts in the install handler.

And finally after all migration is done use the next version to waste the field.

Comment: Good in theory, but 1. Fields have already been deleted, 2. What a nightmare to have 100s of orgs upgrade and wait for that before the next release. Then what about the ones that do not listen...Not to mention the owner has no concept of a release cycle.....

Comment: 1. that given fact can't be changed in your case, so unfortunately my answer may only apply generally as a preemptive measure 2. I think it's not to bad if you have push-major upgrades enabled. Push1 ==> intermediate package ==> let it run until all Orgs complete the migration scripts successfully ==> Push2 ==> field-killer ==> done. Sounds not too hard to me. Of course it would be better to have an out-of-the-box-straight-forward-solution so let us know how your support case is working out.

Comment: Will do. Currently the owner does not want to enable push upgrades....(Maybe this will convince him. )